# Why is it that we don't need to use try-catch block when reading data but we do need try-catch when attaching a Scanner to a file?

Tags: java

Im reading a programming book on The Scanner, and it's saying that we don't need to use try-catch block when reading data because IOException are captured, but we do need try-catch when attaching a Scanner to a file.

for example, in the following code the try-catch is needed. Can you show me an example where try-catch isn't needed but the error is captured by IOException?

```
Scanner scnaFile = null;
String fileName = "dataFile.txt";
try{
    scanFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
     System.err.println(filename + " not found");
     System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Look at the [`Scanner` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.Readable%29). The one that takes a `File` throws a `FileNotFoundException` while the one that takes an `InputStream` (eg: when you read from `System.in`) doesn't throw a checked exception.

Comment: @NullUserException is it possible to enter something into the `InputStream` so that it would blow up?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you show me an example where try-catch isn't needed but the error
>   is captured by IOException?

Example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));  
while (sc.hasNextLong()) {  
   long aLong = sc.nextLong();  
}
```

These `nextXXX`methods will not thrown any exception related to I/O as this is captured in the code.
They will throw an exception though if the input is exausted.
Read the [Scanner Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)